# How to fix unreadable selected text color in Eclipse Mars file properties dialog on Ubuntu?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse Mars (and also previous versions) on Ubuntu (any version) when I select some text in file properties dialog it becomes unreadable because of its color.

Unselected text is OK:

[image]

But selected text is unreadable:

[image]

What settings do I need to change in Eclipse, GTK3 config or anywhere else to make the selected text readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my question:
The issue here is that GtkTextView widget that displays this text in Eclipse (identified by [GTK Inspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK%2B/Inspector)) ignores *background-color* CSS property defined by the desktop theme, but *color* property is applied.

Therefore when the text is selected its *color* is correctly changed to grey based on the theme CSS but the *background-color* defined by the theme as blue, which would make the grey text readable, is ignored for some reason and the result is unreadable combination of grey text on grey background.

This is probably a defect in Eclipse, because GtkTextView widget in other applications applies the *background-color* correctly. The workaround is to select a theme that sets a selected text *color* to something readable on grey Eclipse dialog background or to change the selected text *color* only for GtkTextView  widget by adding this CSS style to the file:

**~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css**

```css
/* Selected text in eclipse file dialog and others.
Other css styles like background-color or font-weight do not seem to work*/
GtkTextView:selected,
GtkTextView:selected:focused,
GtkTextView:selected:backdrop,
GtkTextView:selected:focused:backdrop {
        color: #2ca5d8;

}
```

And the selected text is now readable:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@mmm Great I am also struggling to fix this issue.Thanks.

I am extending your answer little bit further.

Set **background-color** and **color** properties of **GtkTextView** so that selection should looks similarly like in other editors. I used the same color code for **background-color** which is same as **@define-color selected_bg_color** value in `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css`

Where Ambiance is my theme name.

**~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css**

```css
/* Selected text in eclipse file dialog and "Text Areas"others.*/
GtkTextView:selected,
GtkTextView:selected:focused,
GtkTextView:selected:backdrop,
GtkTextView:selected:focused:backdrop {
        background-color: #f07746;
        color: #ffffff;            
}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting that the background-color is working in your eclipse. Then I would also expect it to work from theme CSS which usually has some definition of background-color for all widgets like *:selected {background- color: ...